# Kibana3: long to IP in terms panel

Tags: long-integer, logstash, kibana, ipv4

For an ELK(Kibana is v3) setup I feed logs from some firewalls and src_ip/dst_ip fields are defined as type "ip". eg.

```
"dst_ip" : {"type" : "ip"}
```

Mappings are also correct:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/logstash-2015.03.10/_mapping/field/src_ip?pretty
{
    "logstash-2015.03.10" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "screenos" : {
        "src_ip" : {
          "full_name" : "src_ip",
          "mapping":{"src_ip":{"type":"ip"}}
        }
      },
      "cisco-fw" : {
        "src_ip" : {
          "full_name" : "src_ip",
          "mapping":{"src_ip":{"type":"ip"}}
        }
      },
      "checkpoint" : {
        "src_ip" : {
          "full_name" : "src_ip",
          "mapping":{"src_ip":{"type":"ip"}}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is that in any Terms panel where I want to display topN SRC/DST IP addresses, instead of the dotted decimal representation of an IP address, I have the int/long representation.

e.g.: Instead of 192.168.66.6 it shows 3232252422

Is there any workaround to fix this in Kibana v3 or v4?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because 'ip' is stored internally as a number.  In order to have a string version of the ip address, you need to add it to the mapping and then use ip.raw in your panel:

```
     "MY_FIELD" : {
        "index" : "analyzed",
        "type" : "ip",
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
```